# windows 7 (64bit)driver for Cannon BJC-210

Tags: windows-7, windows

i have windows 7 premium 64bit and was happy until i tried to plug in my printer 
Cannon BJC -210 = ok so i had to get a special cable
but now i seem to find it impossible to get a driver for this to work 
surely this should be possible ?

Comment: special cable? please explain a little more.

Comment: @Kronos it uses DB-25 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port

Answer (score 1):

From [this site](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7hardware/thread/c644a062-a643-4269-a953-75c3d1498ca7):

> The short answer is no, it will not
>   work in Windows 7.  It was designed
>   for Windows 95 and I have to say I
>   haven't seen one this century.  It
>   doesn't even have drivers for Windows
>   XP, although they may well be included
>   in the operating system.  Sorry, but
>   it's just too old for Canon to rewrite
>   drivers, they would much rather have
>   you buy a new printer that they will
>   support for the next 10 years or so.
>
> If you do get something newer, you
>   will find the ink is more economical
>   and the print details is much higher,
>   I don't think you will be too
>   disappointed.

Comment: I'm not surprised - this was one of my first inkjets that I had purchased - before XP was even heard of.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (Win 7 32-bit), but I found the solution, download [the driver](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/bjc_series/bjc_2000_series#DriversAndSoftware) from Canon's home page for the Canon BJC 2000, WIN2000.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, four years late: If you have Windows 7 XP1 running and select "add new printer", the Canon BJC-210 (or any Canon BJC-xxx model) won't show up in the list. But if you then press the Windows Update button and wait for a couple of minutes the drivers for BJC-240 and BJC-265 will pop up. Don't no where W7 got them from, can't find them via the Canon or Microsoft website. Anyway, this might be even better than trying the BJC-2000 drivers. BJC-240 drivers worked for me on 64 bit W7, both color and B&W.